# How to return the correct UIImageView

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimageview

Looking for way to use a function to check the "number" and return the correct UIImageView, instead of having to make a long if statement. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
 randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))    

          if number == 1{
            image1.image = UIImage(named: array[randNumber])
            number += 1
        } else if number == 2{
            image2.image = UIImage(named: array[randNumber])
            number += 1
        } else if number == 3{
            image3.image = UIImage(named: array[randNumber])
            number += 1
        } else if number == 4{
            image4.image = UIImage(named: array[randNumber])
            number += 1
        }
```

If the number is 3, then image3 will be returned

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to shorten the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to shorten your code.

Make an array out of your image views:

```
let imageViewArray = [image1, image2, image3, image4]
```

Generate your random number:

```
randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
```

Here comes the magic. Since the correspondence between the value of `number` and your image view to be used is like this:

```
number    ImageView
1         image1
2         image2
3         image3
4         image4
```

and the array's indices' correspondence with your image views is like this:

```
index     ImageView
0         image1
1         image2
2         image3
3         image4
```

We just need to subtract one from `number` to make it match the array indices. This means that we can use this expression to access the image view we want:

```
imageViewArray[number - 1]
```

The whole line will be like this:

```
imageViewArray[number - 1].image = UIImage(named: array[randNumber])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this is what I've been looking for. I have tried this before and when pasting your code I get the same error: "Value of type 'String' has no member 'image'"

Comment: Are you sure you declared `image1` and other image views as `UIImageView`? @Gjeruldsen

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!

Comment: Nevermind. Just restarted Xcode and now it works perfectly. Thanks again